# how to refresh after server request for login with ember?

Tags: ember.js, authentication, refresh, reload

I have the following code as ember login controller. It works by checking if user is logged_in, but it always returns false.

The `is_logged_in` needs first a refresh before server returns true and then it works. How do I make this work correctly? Also the transition to route isn't working.

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions: {
    userLogin: function(user) {
      $.post("http://siteurl/api/authentication/login/?username=" + user.username + "&password=" + user.password + "");



      $.getJSON("http://siteurl/api/authentication/is_logged_in/", function(json) {
        alert(json.logged_in);
         if(json.logged_in == true){        
            transitionTo('nieuws');
          }
         if(json.logged_in == false){
            alert("login incorrect");
          }
        });
      }
      }
    });
```

Comment: I'm going to have to ask you to halt the coding for a moment. Ask yourself, "Do I really need to use two requests, or does `$.post` provide any sort of callback when the server responds?" Also, do some googling on how to build a login form with Ember. Here's an article to read: http://blog.sensible.io/2013/05/23/how-to-write-a-login-form.html Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second request should be called after the first one has completed. Also you have a couple of errors in your code. Try this:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions: {
    userLogin: function(user) {
      var self = this;
      $.post("http://siteurl/api/authentication/login/?username=" + user.username + "&password=" + user.password + "", function() {
        $.getJSON("http://siteurl/api/authentication/is_logged_in/", function(json) {
          alert(json.logged_in);
          if(json.logged_in == true){        
            self.transitionToRoute('nieuws');
          }
          if(json.logged_in == false){
            alert("login incorrect");
          }
        });
      });
    }    
  }
});
```

In addition, as @Matthew Blancarte points out in a comment, you shouldn't need two requests to login a user. Ther first POST request should return a success/fail result.